# Taylor Polynomial of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I have attached an image of section in Spivak's "Calculus", where the author explains how the difference between a function an it's Taylor's polynomial at a point $a$ is smaller than difference between $x-a$. Then the author says, that it's generalization and that for example for a $f=e^x$ the difference between first order derivative of a function and it's Taylor's polynomial is not so small as to make it higher order small function compared to difference in arguments $x-a$. He says it's easy to demonstrate it by applying L'Hospital's rule two times, but I don't understand why on denominator it's $x^2$ instead of $x$ if $a=0$. Can someone explain?

[image]

Comment: What is on the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x}=0$$ means that, when we are very close to zero, that $e^x-1-x$ tends to zero much faster than $x$.

And $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$ means that, when we are very close to zero, that $e^x-1-x$ tends to zero at approximately the same speed as $x^2$, they are "of the same order", they "look" very similar in the small neighbourhood of zero.

In other words, $\dfrac {x^2}{2}$ is a good approximation of $e^x-1-x$ when we are in a small enough neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: This can be further made more precise, but it is intuitively acceptable.

Comment: In the next paragraph he states that $e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ is higher order small function compared to $x^2$, is there any connection to what you are saying, that $\frac{x^2}{2}$  is a good approximation of $e^x-1-x$?

Comment: In the first limit, as in the second, both numerator and denominator tend to zero when x tends to zero, but, with a difference, the difference is that $e^x-1-x$ tends to zero as $\dfrac{x^2}{2}$, with exactly the same speed, so it tends faster than x, because of that the first limit is zero. The next paragraph shows you that $e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ tends to zero "much" faster than $x^2$. It tends to zero as fast as $\dfrac {x^3}{6}$

Comment: So, very near the zero $e^x-1-x$ and $\dfrac{x^2}{2}$ attain almost the same values. And, very near the zero, $e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $\dfrac {x^3}{6}$ attain almost the same values.

Comment: That is, with almost exactly the same speed (my second comment):

Answer (score 0):

I think, the author wants to express, that the approximation using a taylor polynomial of order 1 is not as "good" as an approximation of degree 2.

More precise, using Landau-Symbols, one can show, that $f(x) - P_{k,a}(x) \in o(|x-a|^k)$ for $x \rightarrow a$.

In your explicit situation you can see, that $f(x) - P_{1,
0} \in o(x)$ for $x \rightarrow 0$, but $f(x) - P_{1,
0} \notin o(x^2)$.